# How to extract multiple zip files in a directory using MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, extract, unzip

I'm trying to extract all the zip files in a directory using MSBuild. Rather than calling unzip task multiple times per each zip file found in the directory, I'd rather to use a loop somehow, for instance:

```
for each zip file in $(directory)
    <unzip file=@(zipFile) targetDirectory=$(destination) />
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, use task batching, like this:

```
<unzip file=%(zipFile.Identity) targetDirectory=$(destination) />
```